# Keyspace 'OpsCenter' does not exist

Tags: datastax, opscenter

When I start datastax-agent look into /var/log/datastax-agent/agent.log, I see following error message:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :opsagent.cassandra/keyspaces-does-not-exist, :message "The OpsCenter storage keyspace, \"OpsCenter\", does not exist yet."} {:object {:type :opsagent.cassandra/keyspaces-does-not-exist, :message "The OpsCenter storage keyspace, \"OpsCenter\", does not exist yet."}, :environment {conn #<SessionManager com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager@374c40ba>, ks-to-set "\"OpsCenter\"", current-ks nil, e #<InvalidQueryException com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Keyspace 'OpsCenter' does not exist>}}
        at opsagent.cassandra$set_ks.invoke(cassandra.clj:28)
        at opsagent.cassandra$get_conn.invoke(cassandra.clj:33)
        at opsagent.cassandra$scan_pdps.invoke(cassandra.clj:180)
        at opsagent.cassandra$process_pdp_row$fn__2465.invoke(cassandra.clj:206)
        at opsagent.cassandra$process_pdp_row.invoke(cassandra.clj:204)
        at opsagent.cassandra$process_pdp_row.invoke(cassandra.clj:202)
        at opsagent.cassandra$load_pdps_with_retry$fn__2471.invoke(cassandra.clj:218)
        at opsagent.cassandra$load_pdps_with_retry.invoke(cassandra.clj:217)
        at opsagent.cassandra$setup_cassandra.invoke(cassandra.clj:275)
        at opsagent.opsagent$setup_cassandra.invoke(opsagent.clj:152)
        at opsagent.opsagent$init_jmx.invoke(opsagent.clj:206)
        at opsagent.opsagent$_main.doInvoke(opsagent.clj:271)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: OpsCenter should create the keyspace on it's own. Can you check in cqlsh and see if it has done so? `desc keyspace OpsCenter`

Comment: have you started the opscenter daemon successfully on the cluster with that node?

Comment: I checked in cqlsh, KS is not there. And no, I am not able to start OpsCenter on the cluster due to this error- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361021/unable-to-launch-opscenter-due-to-error-permission-denied-conf-definitions

Comment: what version of opscenter r u running? have you tried install opscenter in a different host, and later try to add the existing cluster?

Answer (score 1):

you should restart opscenter; I do that is ok!

1. ssh to your deploy opscenter machine;
2. kill -9 opscenter's pid
3. cd your opscenter path
4. cd bin
5. ./opscenter