# Unable to launch opscenter due to error: Permission denied: './conf/definitions/opscenter_defs.tar.gz'

Tags: linux, datastax, opscenter

When I start OpsCenter, I get following error message:

```
 File "build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/Definitions.py", line 271, in updateFiles
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
      File "build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/Definitions.py", line 190, in downloadFile
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './conf/definitions/opscenter_defs.tar.gz'
```

I installed OpsCenter using `DataStaxOpsCenter-5.1.1.2015031808-linux-x64-installer` installer on Cent OS 6.6

I did a `find / -name opscenter_defs.tar.gz` and I can't see this file at all on file system

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the file? `ls -lah`

Comment: Does it work when you run with `sudo`. If so you may just need to `chown` or `chmod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing it on a clean machine.